# Adding one sprite multiple times

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm using a fairly standard piece of code to add a movieclip to the stage using a library link. It's fairly standard code:

```
var Beat:beat = new beat();
```

The trouble is, however that it only adds once, where I need it to add multiple times. How would I go about adding many seperate instances of the 'beat' movieclip to the stage, without making more of them/ more variables.

Comment: If you want to add your sprite multiple times **you need multiple instances**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple instances of a movieclip on the stage without declaring multiple instances in your code, you can use a for loop and store all the movie clips in a single array though:

```
var numOfClips:Number = 5;
var mcArray:Array = new Array();

for(var i=0; i<numOfClips; i++)
{
  var newMC:beat = new beat();
  addChild(newMC);
  mcArray.push(newMC);
}
```

Using the above code you end up with a single array to access all 5 movie clips (cleaner than having 5 completely seperate objects like beat1, beat2, beat3).

More info on arrays: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

Comment: sim don;t you think that it is a copy of my answer?

Comment: Thanks, that works. Turns out my problem was not putting the new instance inside the loop.

Comment: I began typing the answer before yours was posted Lukasz, it's a pretty common piece of code as far as looping and adding to an array goes.

Comment: maybe - but surely you should see that new answer was posted - and yes it is common

Answer (score 4):

create them in the loop

```
var _nHowMany:int = 10;
for(var i:int = 0; i < _nHowMany; i++)
{
    addChild(new beat() as DisplayObject);
}
```

also you can store the reference to them if you need to use it later in a list e.g. `Vector.<beat>` but if not needed then simply create and add to stage (or other container).

best regards

Comment: My apologies, I should have explained more. I'm adding them to the stage via a timer, that executes every 150 ms, and the only part that changes is the x value (which is meant to change).

Comment: post the code you are using to add it as anyway loop or timer loop will work the same